# Minimum of a maximum

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Let $x_0=t$ and $x_1=1-t$. Find $t\in[0,1]$ such that $\max_{x\in[0,1]}|w_1(x)|$ is minimal. Whereas $w_1(x) = (x-x_0)(x-x_1)$.
I don't know how to find a specific value for t here. Anyway here's my attempt: 
I found that

$|w_1(x)| = w(x)$ if $x\in[0,t]$ or $x\in[1-t,1]$ and

$|w_1(x)| = -w(x)$ if $x\in [t,1-t]$

I now need to find $\min_{t\in[0,1]}\max_{x\in[t,1-t]}(-w(x))$.
The expression $\max_{x\in[t,1-t]}(-w(x))$ is maximal at $x=1/2$ (I figured that from a plot I made of $|w(x)|$). So I think I have to find $\min_{t\in[0,1]}(-t^2+t+1/4)$. Am I going anywhere with this?

Comment: You are correct, however you should verify that all possible expressions take their maximum value at $x= \frac 12$, mathematically rather than by looking at a graph. If you don't know how to verify this part, then you can ping me (of course, that's what I'm here for!)

Comment: I don't know how, and I don't know how to ping you either. :)

Comment: Ok, do you know about completing the square?